# How can I do a mysql update with a break point

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have 105000 records that I want to update
I want to change the value of a field called owner_id to a number that I want to set but each one number gets only 15000 record.

so each owner will have 15,000 records assigned to them. I can't user where id <1500 because they are not in order those records are in a table with 4 million records.

Notice I want to do a mass change I am not worried about locking tables at this point

This did not work

```
UPDATE phone_calls SET owner_id = 5 WHERE status = 1 LIMIT 15000, 30000
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: do you want to update 15000 random records where status =1 ?

Comment: yes as long as I give each owner 15,000 records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is not correct. Use this query instead:

```
UPDATE phone_calls SET owner_id = 5 WHERE status = 1 AND owner_id <> 5 LIMIT 15000
```

It will update 15000 records only. The records already updated are excluded.
To update more records, run the query again (or put it in a loop).